# Why operators in script could work without being called?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

Why the operators of bpy can be called without the script calls it?
I have searched for a long time.
[image]

(a screenshot from **Blender Python Tutorial:An Introduction to Scripting [how to learn python for beginners]——by Darkfall**)

In the line 10,*operator draw* is defined like a method of object.
After register the `class Test Panel` and *run script* working,
*operator draw* is working without being called!
I can’t understand why operators can work but nobody call `draw()`,
even not create an object of the class.
I have three possible guess:
1.`bpy.utils.register_class(Test Panel)`maybe auto run every method in the class,or run every operator in the class?
2.The operators are like `__init__`.
It would work after an object of its class being created,
or its class being registered?
3.Every `def` in class(I mean method) would work after *run script* is pressed?

If my guess or English be wrong, please tell me
because I want to know more concept about (blender)python
and know why it works.

Comment: the `draw()` in `bpy.types.Operator` runs when the operator is called. And `draw()` in `bpy.types.Panel` runs when it is registered using `bpy.utils.register_class()`.

Comment: `draw()` is not an operator it a python method.

Comment: `draw()` is used to draw UI element like `label`,`prop` etc.

Comment: the python API is an interface to the underlying C code, there are some callbacks that run in the background when you `register` your class, and it auto-creates instances of your class and runs the methods when needed

Comment: Thank you. I get it !